# regex not matching pattern correctly

Tags: php, regex, grep

The data looks like this

```
cityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblah
```

Currently doing

```
$cityID = preg_grep("/cityID=.\d\&$/", $sometext);

print_r($cityID);
```

Currently printing
    array(
    )

I want it to print
    123456789

Comment: Search for "parse query string".

Comment: @user2864740, actually processing a large converted pcap to text file, looking fr a particular pattern

Comment: Do you want the `.` right after the `=`?

Comment: I thought the . would indicate the start, i removed it, and then also put it at the start of cityID, still not grabbing the city id. cheers @thesquid24

Comment: @user2436729 Please see my new answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$` is marking the end of line, where as this pattern isn't necessarily at the end of a line. Also `\d` is not allowing for more than one digit before the ampersand, so I added a `+`. (Also, be aware that `.` matches any character; it's not clear that is what you want, which is why I asked above.)

This should match for you:

```
preg_match("/cityID=\d+&/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

To experiment more with this pattern, visit http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1WH

Comment: Cheers @thesquid24 I understand it is an awkward request, but i thanks for the guidance. Good to see stackoverflow having some patience!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$str = "cityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblahcityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblahcityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblah";

// or
// $str = "cityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblah
// cityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblah
// cityID=123456789&sharing=blahblahblah";

$result = preg_match_all("/cityID=(\d+)/", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Ouput:

`Array ( [0] => 123456789 [1] => 123456789 [2] => 123456789 )`